# Ubuntu Studio 22.04 forces keyboard layout to English

Tags: kde, ubuntu-studio, plasma-5

I type in 3 languages. Despite setting the switching policy to *Global*, every time when I switch windows, KDE forces the layout back to English, ignoring the last layout. How this behavior can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

The following solution helped me. Delete **~/.config/kxkbrc** file and reboot. Add other layouts via GUI, open **~/.config/kxkbrc**, remove all unnecessary lines, and make the configuration as here:

```
[Layout]
DisplayNames=,,
LayoutList=us,ru,il
Options=grp:alt_shift_toggle,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp
ResetOldOptions=false
SwitchMode=Global
Use=true
VariantList=,,lyx
```