# Ubuntu 22.04.01 forces keyboard layout to English when switching windows

Tags: keyboard, layout

I have a problem, that appears first after upgrading from Ubuntu 21.04 to 22.04.1 LTS.

I use it on Odroid N2+, so AARCH64.
I use xfce in Xorg/xrdp-Sessions.

Before upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04, I started a sh-script with the command "setxkbmap de" and the keyboard layout was correctly set to German and it was not changed/switched automatically.

But now after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04, every time when I switch from a window to another window, the keyboard layout is changed to English.

The "solution" from
[Ubuntu Studio 22.04 forces keyboard layout to English](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404194/ubuntu-studio-22-04-forces-keyboard-layout-to-english/1429984) does not work for me, because there is no `~/.config/kxkbrc`.

Any ideas? Please help!

Comment: You are not setting the keyboard layout in Settings - Keyboard? Set there, it would probably stick.

Comment: This does not work. When connecting to this session it is always set to english.
This was in Ubuntu 21 the same. Then I had to change it with setxkbmap and this works.

But now it is reset every time when I change focus from a window to another window.

Comment: @vanadium But your thought was the way to my solution. I had to change the Standard-Keyboard-Layout in the icon besides the clock (Fcitx 5). This works! Thanks a lot for the thought. (But changing in die Settings did not work!)